# Cannot change one value of an enum because it's a re-assignment of an immutable variable

Tags: enums, rust

I have enums that contain variables:

```
enum Asymmetric {
    One(i32),
    Two(i32, i32),
}
```

I want to change just one field of an already existing enum, without reassigning the entire enum. My code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=acbbeea223f17e16af5c36eda32c1295&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
// Does not compile
fn main() {
    let two = Asymmetric::Two(4, 5);
    let mut vec = vec![two];
    foo(&mut vec[0]);
}

fn foo(baa: &mut Asymmetric) {
    match baa {
        &mut Asymmetric::Two(x0, x1) => {
            x0 = 6;
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

This results in this error:

```
error[E0384]: re-assignment of immutable variable `x0`
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
15 |         &mut Asymmetric::Two(x0, x1) => {
   |                              -- first assignment to `x0`
16 |             x0 = 6;
   |             ^^^^^^ re-assignment of immutable variable
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to "match ergonomics" (introduced in Rust 1.26, [proposed here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md)), you can write your code like this:

```
fn foo(baa: &mut Asymmetric) {
    match baa {
        Asymmetric::Two(x0, _) => {
            *x0 = 6;
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

Since `baa` is a mutable reference, but your pattern you're matching against (`Asymmetric::Two(x0, _)`) is not, the name `x0` is automatically bound as mutable reference.

You can also do it manually by using `ref mut`. See this working code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9d01020d7d2f3eb1b807d10c266f2606&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn foo(baa: &mut Asymmetric) {
    match *baa {
        Asymmetric::Two(ref mut x0, _) => {
            *x0 = 6;
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

---

Some minor changes that are not related to your error, but which increase your code quality:

- usually you deref (with `*`) the `match`ed-on value instead of adding `&` or `&mut` to every pattern in the match
- you should use `_` as a name placeholder if you don't need to bind to that name

In your case, you can simplify the code even further by using `if let`. Whenever you are only interested in one `match`-case, you should use `if let` instead:

```
fn foo(baa: &mut Asymmetric) {
    if let Asymmetric::Two(x0, _) = baa {
        *x0 = 6;
    }
}
```